# mouse drag issue with rxjs

Tags: javascript, rxjs

I am looking at the [mouse drag example](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/filtering/takeuntil.html) from `learnrxjs.io`, it looks pretty straight forward to me.

```
const mousedown$ = fromEvent(document, 'mousedown')
const mouseup$ = fromEvent(document, 'mouseup');
const mousemove$ = fromEvent(document, 'mousemove');

// after mousedown, take position until mouse up
mousedown$.pipe(
  mergeMap(_ => {
    return mousemove$.pipe(
      map((e: any) => ({
        x: e.clientX,
        y: e.clientY
      })),
      // complete inner observable on mouseup event
      takeUntil(mouseup$)
    )
  })
)
.subscribe(console.log);
```

However i can't figure out why the console is logging every second once I do the following:

- Press the mouse
- Keep it pressed and don't move it

Here is the [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-ug2ezf?file=index.ts&devtoolsheight=50)

Can someone help me clarify this?
Thanks!

**Edit:** It seems to happen in Chrome `version 79.0.3945.117 (Official Build) (64-bit)`. I cannot reproduce the issue in Firefox `72.0.1 (64-bit)`...

**Edit 2:** finally ending up restarting my machine and the issue is gone...

Comment: For me it only logs when I click and drag around.

Comment: Ok i have the issue in Chrome `Version 79.0.3945.117 (Official Build) (64-bit)`. In firefox it seems okay.

Comment: For future reference, one way I might have debugged this is logging out the event value that triggers your mergeMap callback. It sounds like Chrome was emitting mouse move events even when you weren't moving.